# Making planes with image sequences run smoother

Tags: materials, performance, cache

I'm working with both audio and video and I can't help but notice that when you add in a plane with an image sequence as a material the viewport fps' drop a lot.

Now I do have several planes with different sequences, but they only lag the first replay, then it's smooth, until you do anything with the planes, whether it's changing the material, moving them or any other interaction.

**Is there a way to cache the sequences permantenly so they don't lag each time I change them?**

Comment: I don't know, but something you can do is change the Sync setting to "Frame Dropping" instead of "Play Every Frame" (in the Timeline, under Playback). It will try to maintain a constant FPS (at the cost of not displaying every frame)

Comment: This is a setting I've always needed but didn't know there was. Would you mind if I answer the question or do you want to?